# WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, axis, axis-labels

I am trying to solve the below issue for last couple of days but still not able to resolve it. I have searched lots of forums but all in vain.

**Little bit of history:* My code was working well in the devp env but for accessing the production sever I received new URL and three new certificates after successfully including the certificates in new trust store file.I am facing below issue. Please help.

```
2013-11-25 11:32:30,373 INFO[BuilderUtil] OMException in getSOAPBuilder 
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]:[1,46]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:198)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:140)
    at org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil.getSOAPBuilder(BuilderUtil.java:686)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:197)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:145)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:108)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:67)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:354)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient$NonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(OutInAxisOperation.java:446)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,46]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:648)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.startDTD(BasicStreamReader.java:2482)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromPrologBang(BasicStreamReader.java:2398)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2058)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1069)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:668)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 14 more
2013-11-25 11:32:30,378 INFO   [BuilderUtil] Remaining input stream :[] 
2013-11-25 11:32:30,380 DEBUG  [AuditUtilities] Request Message Id: urn:uuid:5f75a15c-ad57-4d00-b277-75fe7b1e241d 
2013-11-25 11:32:30,380 DEBUG  [AuditUtilities] Response Message Id: null 
2013-11-25 11:32:30,380 DEBUG  [AuditUtilities] Response Message Data: null
```

My SOAP request seems me correct:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><ns4:product xmlns:ns4="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/xsd/common/CommonCoreElements/3.0" soapenv:mustUnderstand="false"><ns4:vendor><ns1:qualifier xmlns:ns1="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/xsd/common/QualifiedIdentifier/3.0">http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/id/hi/vendorid/1.0</ns1:qualifier><ns1:id xmlns:ns1="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/xsd/common/QualifiedIdentifier/3.0">SDS</ns1:id></ns4:vendor><ns4:productName>HI</ns4:productName><ns4:productVersion>10.1</ns4:productVersion><ns4:platform>LINUX</ns4:platform></ns4:product><h:signature xmlns:h="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/xsd/common/CommonCoreElements/3.0"><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /><ds:Reference URI="#body-c3c18409-d0df-4aed-b294-87af248c61f0"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /><ds:DigestValue>3pGWeWvyYHDdsDTu0F7qATI3Jp4=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference URI="#timestamp-232e1ed9-f97a-4515-89bd-a3683fab0fce"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /><ds:DigestValue>dGJxcKsX+y4jb0ndH1RQDqeWnTw=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference URI="#user-69d4eead-8b69-4e0a-85d7-b2a58867aaa0"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /><ds:DigestValue>9ET9aqC4jkINuYY8OhKsAJPEwX8=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>W24rpxUgpbTzxvJUoj5WpBsEssdaaddd56464t4eyYCAa2q9J0izrWIuukvOovde5h+xxxd1+5h/7JREGERGERGEGEGEGRTH5YT34R3EHYJGBDSEFERHJNFGGFFWEBzj7Jj3wfGs3WOLwsvhCuVBRY79mXTAxyQZYiUl7+tk3Pdm5YcSM0ZKfQJyUChIL1mjxALhwdCJkHOneJenjTgFaGRP+0iPF51TDc7l5ruxw8NdsSuN7P8D6lax3Fa4lck2iW/+t43yJ6cqTjZztMPuyKcYUgFhCS4334534234ERFGWBqyZhgRGFREGREG4543645FGER34WEFW4TERSygB8Gj+nx+217qRFTXD8/vcr8/BA1zWDLR05QdyZSDfuOfWTXpgfDcPTqedteeaww5cetv8L5J0dpFvRUkVDFGFGERcTOzmQALQZ+2C81RaNidKeQz++Q==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></h:signature><ns4:timestamp xmlns:ns4="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/xsd/common/CommonCoreElements/3.0" xml:id="timestamp-232e1ed9-f97a-4515-89bd-a3683fab0fce"><ns4:created>2013-11-25T11:32:27.296+11:00</ns4:created><ns4:expires>2013-11-25T12:32:27.296+11:00</ns4:expires></ns4:timestamp><ns4:user xmlns:ns4="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/xsd/common/CommonCoreElements/3.0" xml:id="user-69d4eead-8b69-4e0a-85d7-b2a58867aaa0"><ns1:qualifier xmlns:ns1="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/xsd/common/QualifiedIdentifier/3.0">http://sdspathology.com.au/id/hi/userid/1.0</ns1:qualifier><ns1:id xmlns:ns1="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/xsd/common/QualifiedIdentifier/3.0">TEST_SDS_USER_ID</ns1:id></ns4:user><wsa:To>https://www3.medicareaustralia.gov.au/pcert/soap/services/</wsa:To><wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:5f75a15c-ad57-4d00-b277-75fe7b1e241d</wsa:MessageID><wsa:Action>http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/svc/ConsumerSearchIHIBatchAsync/3.0/ConsumerSearchIHIBatchAsyncPortType/submitSearchIHIBatchRequest</wsa:Action></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body xml:id="body-c3c18409-d0df-4aed-b294-87af248c61f0"><ns12:submitSearchIHIBatch xmlns:ns12="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/svc/ConsumerSearchIHIBatchAsync/3.0"><ns12:searchIHIBatchRequest><searchIHI xmlns="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/xsd/consumermessages/SearchIHI/3.0"><s36:medicareCardNumber xmlns:s36="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/xsd/consumercore/ConsumerCoreElements/3.0">2950249651</s36:medicareCardNumber></searchIHI><ns11:requestIdentifier xmlns:ns11="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/xsd/consumermessages/SearchIHIBatch/3.0">d1f21610-6cb9-4e60-9673-18f43a4500b5</ns11:requestIdentifier></ns12:searchIHIBatchRequest></ns12:submitSearchIHIBatch></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Note that this is one of those pointless XML syntax rules that shows it wasn't designed by language designers.

Comment: You've already asked your question. Comments intended to 'bump' it don't have that effect here. Please delete them.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue in production server. Tried the suggested options but still getting this error. Can any one tell me how to fix it.
Here is the error message :

`ERROR [stderr] (pool-1544-thread-1) Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers
ERROR [stderr] (pool-1544-thread-1)  at [row,col,system-id]: [1,50,"http://XXX.XXX.XX.XX:9080/meaweb/wsdl/web_WS_INCID_STATUS.wsdl"]`

Comment: Similar issue.

In the case I experienced, this was a piece of code that had not been used in decades.
The problem was that the @WebServiceClient was completely stale. Target namespaces and all that were senseless in realation to the running WSDL generated by weblogic.

A Quick wsimport to re-generate a sane webservice client, got rid of the exception.

Answer (score 12):

Had a very similar issue. The WSDL file is delivered, but calls on the bind address fail with this bogus doctype error. In our prod environment, http requests coming from outside the corporate network are swapped across to https. The solution was to request the WSDL file using https, then everything worked.

Comment: My solution was similar - not http->https, but the server responded with HTTP Status Code 301 Moved Permanently, which caused a similar problem. Fixed by adressing the wsdl with the new url.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the response is not XML, it is most likely a HTML page. In my case, the SOAP service I was requesting did not exist so I was getting a HTML error page, which starts like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
```

There error is referring to that second-last character, the double quote.

Comment: Same thing here, there response was a "bad request" because the application was sending on a http:// endpoint on port 443 (it should have been https:// if it's using 443, or 80 if it's using http). Using a browser, SoapUI and wireshark helped me (if you need tips).

Comment: For me too, someone configured the enpoint to some index.xhtml ...

Comment: How can we get the HTML response returned by Server. In my case, I am getting org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException. Is there a way to extract this response before Axis tries to map it to an envelope? (which is failing since it's an HTML response)

Comment: I had same error. In  my hbm file the  the DTD was not surrounded by double quotes. http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd.
So below line in hbm with quotes fixed it. 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
You should have a syntax error at line 46 in your wsdl file

```
[row,col {unknown-source}]:[1,46]
```

Comment: technically the syntax error will be on line 45 if the file starts on line 1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I always receive this error when the response of my request is an unexpected HTML. I usually receive this response when I call to a request (URI) that the server doesn`t know and go back a 404 error code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message, but that is also for XML attributes as..:

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name=id>48</field> <!-- Incorrect -->
    <field name="id">48</field><!-- Correct -->
    .....
  </doc>
</add>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an ampersand symbol (&) in a table, and then I used Jira's Page Properties Report macro to show that content from that cell, and it was failing with a similar error.