# Is there any relation between web service call and browser cookies?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap

We are calling a web service in our application. While clicking a button to call that web service, our request seems to be failed and we got an error message as follows:

```
An error occurred while invoking the Web Service. Details: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,50] (APNX-1-4044-000)
```

Only sometimes, we are getting this error. There is no resemblance in that success flow of web service call. When we get this error, as a trouble shooting try, we have cleared all the browser cookies and retried for the same inputs. It is working fine.

Is there any relation between calling a web service and browser cookies?

We are getting this error only when using SOAP but not while using REST.

Could any one please assist on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use curl, wget or something like this to try your webservice calls https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US

Comment: @joseph The project has already gone live. We can't change the core concept. If so, we have to provide the cause for this issue. Can you please  tell us any cause for this error? That would be more helpful.

Comment: those are tools that will help you test and debug your webservice calls, no changes to the deployment

Comment: We will try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say how your application is coded. But one thing for sure, cookies are the ones which maintains user logged in states in your browser ( Again If your container is told to use cookie based ). Check the cookie for your domain. it should have some set of values. observe these set of values and try to find if there is any association when the web service call is made.

However, I can't say if it is very specific you cookies, but [WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183151/wstxunexpectedcharexception-unexpected-character-code-34-in-doctype-decla) seems to be reported , this may help

Comment: I am sure about one thing here. We are not getting this error at the start of the day since the cookies for that day will be empty. Have you heard any similar issue on web services with respect to cookies?