# Jackson XmlMapper - JsonParseException: Unexpected character '&'

Tags: java, jackson, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an XML string to a Java object using `fasterxml.jackson.xml.XmlMapper`.

The problem is that the XML string contains the character '&'.

I am getting an exception thrown

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected character '&' in prolog; expected '<'.
```

#### Code

```
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

public class MyProblem {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      XmlMapper = xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
      String myXML = "<cookies>Chocolate&Butter cocunut</cookies>";  
      Map<String, String> myTester = xmlMapper.reader().readValue(myXML, Map.class);
   }
}
```

I was expecting it to work when I perform a `System.out.println(myTester);`

After reading XmlMapper's documentation, I believe there is a property I can set that I can use to override deserialization functionalities.

If I need to escape these special characters, how to do?

Comment: Read about [XML prolog](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd), kind of a header containing XML-version information, etc. like `<?xml version="1.0"?>`. It is missing in your given XML string.

Answer (score 1):

Because of [the special role of ampersand character in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500800/how-can-i-include-an-ampersand-character-in-an-xml-document) it must be

- either enclosed as CDATA `"<cookies><![CDATA[Chocolate&Butter cocunut]]></cookies>"`
- or as HTML-entity `"<cookies>Chocolate&amp;Butter cocunut</cookies>"`

Both would be valid XML strings that Jackson and the underlying Woodstox can parse.

See also [XML Spec, 2.4 Character Data and Markup](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax):

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) MUST NOT appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they MUST be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings " & " and " < " respectively. The right angle bracket (>) may be represented using the string " > ", and MUST, for compatibility, be escaped using either " > " or a character reference when it appears in the string " ]]> " in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA section.

Related questions:

- [How to solve Ampersand (&) conversion issue in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423495/how-to-solve-ampersand-conversion-issue-in-xml)
- ["Content is not allowed in prolog" error yet nothing before XML declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51500738/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-error-yet-nothing-before-xml-declaration)
- [WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183151/wstxunexpectedcharexception-unexpected-character-code-34-in-doctype-decla)